# Nodejs request behaves differently than Postman and Curl

Tags: node.js, curl, request, postman

I've been messing with that for a while now and can't seem to figure it out... I'm trying to send a POST request to a device (what device doesn't matter I guess) in order to change it's IP address. Usually, the setup is done through the browser, so I'm trying to emulate that request. It seems to be working fine when I make the request with Postman or Curl but not with the request module from Node.js. 
All requests return a 200 OK status code but the latter seems to be not accepted. This is the request I perform using Postman:

```
POST /configuration_tab/ajax_comb_table_save/network_config/network_config_schema HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.250
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: PHPSESSID=mg37okvhkr1eqv1okq99i98i62
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 234ece69-c3f8-2d29-34a5-c40f8e64f708

form=Hostname%3D%26IPv4mode%3Dstatic%26IPv4address%3D192.168.1.250%26
IPv4netmask%3D255.255.255.0%26IPv4gateway%3D0.0.0.0%26DNSmode%3Dmanual%26
IPv4DNS1%3D%26IPv4DNS2%3D%26IpAddrCnflctDetectEnbl%3Denable%26NtpServer%3D%26
SyslogServer%3D%26SyslogPort%3D514%26SshServerEnable%3Denable
```

This is what I sent through curl:

```
curl -X POST "http://192.168.1.250/configuration_tab/ajax_comb_table_save/network_config/network_config_schema" 
-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" 
-H "Cookie:PHPSESSID=mg37okvhkr1eqv1okq99i98i62" 
-d "form=Hostname%3D%26IPv4mode%3Dstatic%26IPv4address%3D192.168.1.250%26IPv4netmask%3D255.255.255.0%26IPv4gateway%3D0.0.0.0%26DNSmode%3Dmanual%26IPv4DNS1%3D%26IPv4DNS2%3D%26IpAddrCnflctDetectEnbl%3Denable%26NtpServer%3D%26SyslogServer%3D%26SyslogPort%3D514%26SshServerEnable%3Denable"
```

Again, both of them work fine. Now, this is the code I was using to try the same thing via Node:

```
let body = "form=Hostname%3D%26IPv4mode%3Dstatic%26IPv4address%3D192.168.1.250%26IPv4netmask%3D255.255.255.0%26IPv4gateway%3D0.0.0.0%26DNSmode%3Dmanual%26IPv4DNS1%3D%26IPv4DNS2%3D%26IpAddrCnflctDetectEnbl%3Denable%26NtpServer%3D%26SyslogServer%3D%26SyslogPort%3D514%26SshServerEnable%3Denable"

request({
    url: "http://192.168.1.250/configuration_tab/ajax_comb_table_save/network_config/network_config_schema",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=mg37okvhkr1eqv1okq99i98i62",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: body
}, (err, resp) => {
    // Do whatever...
});
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be different or anything I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is data you are sending is from form or application/json?

Comment: can you try with `request.post({.....`

Comment: Have you tired `form` rather that `body`?